# JuiceUI menu breaking upon ASP.NET Postback with pagination bar

Tags: asp.net, dopostback, juice-ui

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web site with JuiceUI menus set up.  When the pages come up by default things look fine.  On my pages where there is a table display (using GridView in the code) and pagination at the bottom, calls to do a PostBack like

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView21','Page$3')
```

cause the JuiceUI menus to break.

The error code in the web developer console says

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eval' of null

with a full trace of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'eval' of null juice.js:97
(anonymous function) juice.js:97
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.js:605
(anonymous function) juice.js:96
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.8.2.js:611
ready juice.js:55
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1082
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:406
DOMContentLoaded
```

Seems to be related to the fact that when the page is first loaded the following watch expression is seen:

```
widget.options: Object 
proto: Object
```

After clicking the pagination #, the values change to:

```
widget.options: Object 
icons: Object 
menu: null 
position: Object 
proto: Object
```

What is causing the menu to be null in widget options upon doPostback and is there anything I can do to fix this?

Can someone shed light on what is going on and what could be done to fix this??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the code.

Had to change the juice.js file from:

```
        $.each( widget.options, function( prop ) {
            if( this.eval ){
                var on = this.on;
```

to:

```
        $.each( widget.options, function( prop ) {
            if( this && this.eval ){
                var on = this.on;
```

FYI this worked fine in IE even without the change but was broken in Chrome and Firefox.  Including the 'this' check fixed this.  Hopefully the juice developers see this post and make the change or reply to this.